# npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server"

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular, npm

I modified the app/main.ts according to [this tutorial](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/accelerating-through-angular-2/level/1/section/1/a-basic-component) and when I "npm start" I get the following errors:

Here's the project file with commit message `error`: https://github.com/monajalal/angular2_projects

```
import {bootstrap}    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import {AppComponent} from '@angular/core'

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: '<h1>Ultra Racing</h1>'

})
class AppComponent{}
bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

errors:

```
Monas-MacBook-Pro:my-proj mona$ npm start

> angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start /Users/mona/angular/my-proj
> tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 

app/app.component.ts(5,25): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,27): error TS1005: ':' expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,33): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,41): error TS1005: ':' expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,43): error TS1005: ',' expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,47): error TS1139: Type parameter declaration expected.
app/app.component.ts(5,52): error TS1002: Unterminated string literal.
app/app.component.ts(6,1): error TS1005: ',' expected.

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.8.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.8.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start: `tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" `
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the angular2-quickstart@1.0.0 start script 'tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" '.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the angular2-quickstart package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     tsc && concurrently "tsc -w" "lite-server" 
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls angular2-quickstart
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /Users/mona/angular/my-proj/npm-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified `app/app.component.ts`:
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: "<h1>Mona's first Angular 2 App</h1>"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

It was due to ' after Mona and I had to use " to fix it. It was told to me by "Rob Wormald" of Google at Angular Gitter Channel.

Comment: Just a suggestion: instead of using " use back ticks `

Answer (score 1):

In your main.ts you should have:

```
import { bootstrap }    from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart